# Connecting CI with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

i know that this question already asked like 100 times

but im really desperated here

i use windows 7

usually , i use Code Igniter to code PHP and MYSQL as my database

i use 
xampp 1.8.1 
[PHP: 5.4.7]

in application\config\database.php , i use

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'test';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and inside my system\database\DB_driver.php , i use

```
    var $dbdriver       = 'mysql';
    var $dbprefix       = '';
    var $char_set       = 'utf8';
    var $dbcollat       = 'utf8_general_ci';
    var $autoinit       = TRUE; // Whether to automatically initialize the DB
    var $swap_pre       = '';
    var $port           = '';
    var $pconnect       = FALSE;
    var $conn_id        = FALSE;
    var $result_id      = FALSE;
    var $db_debug       = FALSE;
    var $benchmark      = 0;
    var $query_count    = 0;
    var $bind_marker    = '?';
    var $save_queries   = TRUE;
    var $queries        = array();
    var $query_times    = array();
    var $data_cache     = array();
    var $trans_enabled  = TRUE;
    var $trans_strict   = TRUE;
    var $_trans_depth   = 0;
    var $_trans_status  = TRUE; // Used with transactions to determine if a rollback should occur
    var $cache_on       = FALSE;
    var $cachedir       = '';
    var $cache_autodel  = FALSE;
    var $CACHE; // The cache class object
```

and inside my controller ,i use

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM asal');
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            echo $row['asalid'];
        }
```

it works perfectly

but that's mysql with php

now that i need to connect my PHP with microsfot SQL Server 2008 R2

this is what i have been through

First, i install sqlsrv driver (SQLSRV30.exe), from here 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

(it said that php 5 should use SQLSRV30)

Next, i extract it to my php/ext

now in my php/ext i already have 8 additional files extracted from SQLSRV30.exe as

```
php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll

php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
```

Then,
i also have tried to add these sentences

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
```

inside my php.ini

Last,

i change my application\config\database.php to

```
    $db['default']['hostname'] = 'NB-EDP-04\SQLEXPRESS';
    $db['default']['username'] = '';
    $db['default']['password'] = '';
    $db['default']['database'] = 'test';
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

also my system\database\DB_driver.php to

```
    var $dbdriver       = 'sqlsrv';
    var $dbprefix       = '';
    var $char_set       = 'utf8';
    var $dbcollat       = 'utf8_general_ci';
    var $autoinit       = TRUE; // Whether to automatically initialize the DB
    var $swap_pre       = '';
    var $port           = '';
    var $pconnect       = FALSE;
    var $conn_id        = FALSE;
    var $result_id      = FALSE;
    var $db_debug       = FALSE;
    var $benchmark      = 0;
    var $query_count    = 0;
    var $bind_marker    = '?';
    var $save_queries   = TRUE;
    var $queries        = array();
    var $query_times    = array();
    var $data_cache     = array();
    var $trans_enabled  = TRUE;
    var $trans_strict   = TRUE;
    var $_trans_depth   = 0;
    var $_trans_status  = TRUE; // Used with transactions to determine if a rollback should occur
    var $cache_on       = FALSE;
    var $cachedir       = '';
    var $cache_autodel  = FALSE;
    var $CACHE; // The cache class object
```

but no good, i keep getting this error after i type localhost/edp at my URL

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\edp\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 127
```

and i test using microsoft c# application

i try to connect to the same database, and it works

i can select the table inside that database

so i think , my database's remote connections already activated

please help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

okay it solved

my problem was the native client

i go to control panel > program and features

i search for "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client'

(because i use microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2)

it will say , it is not recommended to uninstall the native client, but it's okay , as long as we install other native client

and i download

"Microsoft SQL Server 2012 native client"

and , it solved , i dont know what happens, i just know , that it helps my php application connect to ms sql server 2008 R2